# How can we get a vacant, custom URL for Google+

Tags: google-plus, url

We need a Google+ custom URL for our company. However, Google suggests one different from what we wanted.

How can we acquire our particular, vacant, custom URL?

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much can’t. Not at the moment anyway.

> Your custom URL can’t be changed. **It will be preassigned** based on things like your name or the name of your linked website. You may also need to add a few letters or numbers to make it unique to you.

[Source](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2676340).

Comment: Weird, http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/10/29/google-starts-offering-custom-urls-accounts-30-days-old-10-followers-profile-photo/ claims that we can

Comment: It actually says “and Google prepares your custom URL”.